# Which property features the most Firefly actors?

Tags: firefly, actors

The actors in Firefly have since appeared in numerous other sci-fi tv shows and movies.

### Which show/movie has the most Firefly actors? Does any property have all of the main cast members?

Note: The actors need not have recurring roles. A cameo is enough to qualify.

Comment: [One](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303461/) comes to mind. ;)

Comment: The answer is Firefly; I suspect that you would want to reword to obtain a different answer :-)

Comment: @Paul I was going to say "besides for Firefly", but I somehow thought that it wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @ibid Just givin' you a hard time of course.

Comment: @ibid Stating what seems obvious to ourselves is often necessary, for it is not necessarily as obvious to others as it is to ourselves - and others may wish, entirely benevolently, to correct our misconceptions by pointing out the obvious things we've apparently missed.

Comment: @user867 I doubt that anyone thought that I didn't know the Firefly actors appeared in Firefly.

Comment: @Paul I would've (probably) done the same.

Comment: If this is excluding firefly then it may just be too broad.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage there only is one correct answer. (Unless it's a tie.)

Comment: Do you want to clarify which Firefly actors qualify?   You imply they have to be main cast from your second question.   But I could lawyer the first to infer that any cameo on Firefly qualified as a Firefly actor.   That would be a very different question.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Any actor who appeared in Firefly qualifies, but the main cast gets bonus points.

Comment: @ibid:   Ugg -- I'm afraid that's going to change the answer and make it impractical.   Do you want to reconsider?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Only significant characters, not random extras.

Comment: @ThePopMachine FWIW I'm happy with the answer I've accepted, but if someone gives me a better answer (i.e. one with more of the actors) I'll accept it instead.

Comment: @ibid: unfortunately, since IMDB's "credited with" search only returns results where the actors appear together *in the same episode*, it doesn't really work for finding shows that two actors have in common. Thus, if you add even just the guest stars from Firefly to the list, the task balloons exponentially. That said, when I get home tonight, I plan to look up at least Saffron, Niska, and the brothel lady.

Comment: @Martha sounds like someone should write a program that searches for whole series on imdb. I'll add this to my list of things to do which I'll probably never do.

Comment: I know I promised at one point to look up a few of the more significant guest stars, but even just the main cast is getting hard to keep track of. (They keep showing up on *Castle*, which I've been unable to force myself to watch for the longest time.)

Comment: @Martha - I absolve you from your promise :) You can keep the fifteen points.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you want to discount anything that's Firefly-related, the winner is ***[Con Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4642170/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast)***, <strike>Wash</strike> [ahem, sorry] Alan Tudyk's pet project. It has six of the main actors, although not all in the same episodes.

- Alan Tudyk
- Nathan Fillion
- Sean Maher
- Jewel Staite
- Summer Glau
- Gina Torres

As of May 2016, second place goes to ***[Castle](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1219024/?ref_=tt_ov_inf)***, with 5 veterans:

- Nathan Fillion
- Adam Baldwin
- Gina Torres
- Summer Glau
- Jewel Staite

Third place is a tie between ***CSI*** (oddly enough) and ***Justice League***.

***[CSI: Crime Scene Investigation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0247082/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_2)*** has had the following main Firefly actors, although definitely not in the same episodes. (Which means that the show doesn't come up if you do a "credited with" search on IMDB.)

- Ron Glass
- Summer Glau
- Alan Tudyk
- Gina Torres

The ***[Justice League](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0275137/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_43)*** animated TV series has also had four of our actors doing voices:

- Adam Baldwin
- Morena Baccarin
- Gina Torres
- Nathan Fillion

Honorable mention: **Buffy-verse** has had four actors, but not in the same series. Nathan was in ***Buffy*** itself, and Summer, Adam, and Gina all appeared in the spin-off ***Angel***.

5th place is a three-way tie between the aforementioned ***Angel*** and the video games ***Halo 3*** and ***Halo 3: ODST***, which both had Adam, Alan, and Nathan.

Looking at it from the actor's perspective, Adam Baldwin has shared the screen most often with his erstwhile co-stars, with 19 of his shows having at least one other Firefly alum. The person who has worked on the same shows as her co-stars the least is Jewel, with only 4 shows: ***Con Man***, ***The X Files*** (Adam),  ***Warehouse 13*** (Sean), and ***Castle***. The numbers are:

- Adam 19
- Alan 18
- Gina 13
- Jewel 4
- Morena 8
- Nathan 16
- Ron 5
- Sean 9
- Summer 11

Comment: Arrowverse had at least three.

Comment: That harpoon you've put through Wash's name seems a bit harsh ;)

Comment: @TonyMeyer: not my fault. Sniff.

Answer (score -1):

The [Firefly mobile RPG](https://keepflying.com/) features **all of the original cast** along with several of the supporting characters such as Niska (who will provide the players with a continuous stream of jobs and missions).

> At the Firefly panel Thursday night of Comic-Con, the cast members
>   announced they would be providing voices for Firefly Online, an
>   upcoming mobile role playing game set in the ‘verse of the series.
>   Fillion, Gina Torres, Adam Baldwin, and the rest of the main cast will
>   lend their voices to the game, while Alan Tudyk will provide “multiple
>   voices” for different characters. Given Tudyk’s experience voice
>   acting in animated films — Wreck-It Ralph, Frozen, and Big Hero 6 —
>   it’s no wonder why he’ll be providing more voices aside from that of
>   his original character, Wash.

You may wish to note that the beta was launched a while ago, but the full game seems to be stuck in [development hell](https://keepflying.com/news/a-note-from-john-oneill).

Comment: I never even thought about games, but I guess that they would qualify. However, answering that Firefly has Firefly actors [does not](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117831/which-property-features-the-most-firefly-actors?noredirect=1#comment288495_117831).

Comment: @ibid - My philosophy is to never, ever resist the urge to play with the question instead of answering it properly.

Comment: Hey, you know, there was this little movie called *Serenity* that had all of the Firefly cast... oh, wait. Nevermind.

Comment: @Martha - Never heard of it.

Comment: @Richard: in that case, you might not want to read Tony Meyer's comment on my answer - it's a bit spoiler-y.